# Mex-File hangs with JAVA

Tags: java, matlab, mex

I compiled a mex-file from a C++ code which use GMP and some uint64_t (I'm on a winXP 32 bits).

This C++ code works perfectly in C++.

But I noticed it just hangs when I run the mex-file in Matlab for some inputs (it just hangs, I have to kill the process).

What I don't understand, it's that if I run it using the -nojvm Matlab mode, it works perfectly.
So I guess it's related to the Java Virtual Machine. I already tried to increase the heap limit to 1024mo, but it didn't fixed the problem.

When I manually follow the Matlab run when it hangs, the C++ instructions seems to stop without explanation (not an infinite loop or something).

Each time I increased the java heap limit, the Matlab process memory seemed to increase too. But if I run the exact same code in a classic main.cpp C++ file, it doesn't seem to use as memory.

It's really weird.

Comment: You've described a problem, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question?

Comment: My question would be : why the use of Java in Matlab modifies the run of the mex-code ?
What could I try to figure out what happens (I don't really know how to "debug" or find logs of JVM). I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what doesn't work, maybe you have some ideas.

Comment: can you come up with a minimal example we can try to reproduce the problem? I dont think the JVM has anything to do with MEX-files hanging...

Comment: Try to step through your C++ code while it's being executed as a MEX function; then you might get some insight as to what is happening. To do this you need to attach a code-aware debugger to MATLAB (with Visual Studio this is easy, but I don't know what environment you're using).